# I want this json to be displayed in angular

Tags: php, angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-repeat

I want this multilevel array of jason in angular format i am not being able to do it.
     Json file to be displayed in angular goes here. 
     I am able to display properties and geometry not others

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",   //first fie
   "metadata": {
   "generated": 1456209730000,
   "api": "1.4.0",
 },
   "features": [
    {
       "type": "Feature",
       "properties": {
       "mag": 2.3,
  },
   "geometry": {
    "type": "Point",
    "coordinates": [
     -150.7703,
      63.5849
  ]},
  "id": "ak12869032"
 },
 {
  "type": "Feature",
    "properties": {
    "mag": 2.43
  },
   "geometry": {
     "type": "Point",
     "coordinates": [
     -120.8253326,
      36.6078339
    ]},
    "id": "nc72596150"
   }],
"bbox": [                 //last field
   -150.7703,
   33.7698333
    ]}
```

Comment: specify your question,what you have tried?

Comment: BTW that json is having error

Comment: This is a geojson type for showing map coordinates. http://geojson.io

Comment: I have no idea how to do it :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please follow these steps:

1) create `$scope.tempData` variable in your  controller

2) get your value in `$scope`

3) `$scope.tempData=[your json data];`

4) you can use tempData in anywhere within controller.

```
for(var d in tempData)
{
    var data=tempData[d].id;
}
```

now you are able to getting id from your json.but for its giving last value.
so you can cretae array and pushed on every loop.

5) if you want use in html can use `ng-repeat`.

If you are beginner vist my [blog](http://bikeshsrivastava.blogspot.in/).

Answer (score 0):

Edit your json:

```
{
  "type": "FeatureCollection",
  "metadata": {
   "generated": 1456209730000,
   "api": "1.4.0",
    "count": 3
 },
  "features": [
    {
       "type": "Feature",
       "properties": {
       "mag": 2.3,
       "place": "93km WNW of Cantwell, Alaska",
       "time": 1456207082000
 },
      "geometry": {
        "type": "Point",
        "coordinates": [
         -150.7703,
          63.5849
    ]
     },
      "id": "ak12869032"
    },
 {
      "type": "Feature",
        "properties": {
        "mag": 2.43,
        "place": "42km WSW of Mendota, California",
        "time": 1456206494170
  },
       "geometry": {
         "type": "Point",
         "coordinates": [
         -120.8253326,
          36.6078339
    ]
      },
        "id": "nc72596150"
       }
    ],
    "bbox": [
       -150.7703,
       33.7698333,
     0.79,
     -115.9471667,
      63.5849,
      8.8
     ]
   }
```

See the points: http://bl.ocks.org/d/60bc280edef4ed4da464

Comment: yes but how am i supposed to display it in angular table?

Answer (score 0):

To display json in angularjs, please use filter json with model.

```
<input type="text" ng-model="(jsonData | json)">{{jsonData | json}}</input>
```

Comment: I have never used json filter I am new at angular . I have just used ng-repeat

Comment: You can format datatype using filters. It makes your job easy. To display 300000 as 300,000 use currency filter as {{ costApples | currency:2 }}. Similarly to display json assign it to ng-model="Revoluza" and display model as {{ Revoluza | json }}. I have tried it successfully in my code which cannot be shown here.

Comment: do I have to use key value pair for it?

Comment: No. In your controller, first create an empty json object as $scope.Revoluza = [{name:"",address:[{placeA:""},{placeB:""}]}]. Then assign values when required like $scope.Revoluza.name = "abc"; or $scope.Revoluza[0].name = $scope.abcValue, if u want to assign an existing model's value to it. Please build arrays carefully as you can push values into it after referencing it by index values. $scope.Revoluza[0].address[0].placeA = "Milan";

Comment: how can i assign all the values to cope there are so many of them. I am extremely sorry but I really don't have much idea regarding this and I am trying to implement it asap.

Comment: If you have json data in your controller you can display simply by adding filter to the scope variable where you are defining json data object and displaying as shown. Since your knowledge is limited please spend time in understanding this concept. ASAP is not possible for your case.

Answer (score 0):

Using Pre Tag we can style it in html page

```
In your Controller:

$scope.details={name:"xyz",address:[{place:"cc"},{place:"second"}]}

In HTML Page: <pre>{{details|json}}</pre>
```

Comment: there is not just one value how can I assign all the details to scope variable there are so many fields which are not even shown in the able code. I am sorry but I am just not getting it as I don't know much of angular